# PHP Curl with port number issue

Tags: php, curl, port

This is a problem using PHP with Curl (on hosted server). I am trying to control a remote device (LED state) on port `54512` (for example). The `$url` includes the `IP:port` number concatenated with a short CGI command.

The following is a code fragment;

```
$sensorIP = "77.134.85.187:54512"; // IP:port format

$url = $sensorIP . "/setParam.cgi?DOStatus_02=0" ; // set E2210 LED off

echo $url; // 

$result =  accessURL ($url); // set LED state on E2210 remote unit
```

This code times out.  When I use the $url as an address in a web browser it works fine. So the receiving port 54512 is not blocked. When I use `IP:80` to form `$url` it works fine (receiving port set to 80).I tried using the `CURLOPT_PORT` option and the PHP script still times out.

The sending server outgoing HTTP is NOT blocking any port numbers, I checked with my hosting company. They believe I have a programming error, but where?

Comment: Is the server attached to the LED blocking the connection? If you're connected to the same LAN as that server, head to http://www.yougetsignal.com/ and check the Port Forwarding Tester.

Comment: Thanks, but the server is hosted and the remote device is in a different state. using the formed $url with 54512 port number, I can control the LED state from my iphone using Safari. No blocking.

Comment: If the error is in your code, it is most likely inside accessURL().
My first bet is that you should add http:// at the start - curl can do more then just HTTP and if you're using a custom port number, it can hardly gues the protocol.

Answer (score 4):

Workarounds:

1. Try `$sensorIP = "http://77.134.85.187:54512";`
2. Make sure the outbound port 54512 is open (check with your hosting provider)
3. After `curl_exec()` function, add `$output = curl_getinfo($ch);` and print and check the output. you can get some info from that.
4. Dont include port number as part of url. Use the following instead:

   `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, '54512');`

Comment: Thanks to George, Joey and Zack, I have already done all that you have suggested before my post. One exception is not adding  http://. I  assumed that since IP:80 works IP:54512 should work. I will give this a try.

Comment: I tried adding  http:// and again curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, '54512'), no luck. True, I am not showing the accessURL ($url) function but it's very short and does a Curl_init() and Curl_Setop() calls. It is not to blame since IP:80 works.I called my hosting provider and they "guarantee" that port 54512 is not blocked on OUTGOING HTTP sends and the receiving device definitely has an open port since I can contact it with my iPhone using $url. Odd for sure. Al

Comment: I discovered that I can use any outgoing port < 100. So there is some oddity on the hosted platform I am using. It should support any outgoing port < 64K. My provider is in denial but my tests prove otherwise. So Curl/PHP users beware of this odd issue on at lease one or more hosted server platforms. Al

Answer (score -1):

I came across the same problem lately. 
I've tried almost everything, but no luck yet
As far as I understood, curl does not work with other ports except 80.
So the best solution here is to address curl on port 80 and you won't have any problems as I do now.
Hope this info will help you.